# Google + PhotoHunt Java sample not accessible by ip

Tags: google-plus

I am trying to run the PhotoHunt Java sample, https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt/java. The problem I am seeing is the service can only be accessed by `http://localhost:8888`. Google + sign-in button works fine, so I assume all the configuration is correct. Buy if I try to use `http://<some_ip>:8888`, it is not accessible. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Change the app engine server to run on a different port. Select the menu on the Eclipse **Run** button and then click **Run Configurations**. Select the tab for **Arguments**. Next, add the following line:

```
--address=<yourhostaddress>
```

And optionally set the port as well. The following screenshot shows a configured application.

[image: Configured app engine project for PhotoHunt Java]

Now when you run the application, it will serve on the assigned address and port.